# Driver corrupts OS

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, screen, driver, corrupt

I've been working on a PI project, I am using Waveshare 7" touchscreen, now I need to download driver to enable touchscreen, I tried downloading it from their website: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD and it auto restarts my PI and after that it will be stuck on rainbow screen. I reinstalled OS and again when I downloaded driver it did same thing again. I also tried to insert plugin for touchscreen in config.txt in OS image as its shown on Waveshare page, that also didn't work.

any help, mybe anyone now other drivers I could use...?

Comment: what exactly did you download?

Comment: @jsotola I copied this code in terminal: git clone https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show.git 
cd LCD-show/
chmod +x LCD7-1024x600-show
./LCD7-1024x600-show

Comment: I've always found waveshare drivers work well - as long as you use the CORRECT script for the device

Comment: @JaromandaX I copy pasted it from their site, so I think the script is correct

Comment: you're running the script for 1024x600 7 inch - but you linked to the 800x480 7 inch wiki - so, which is it? 1024x600 or 800x480? - oh, wait, that wiki is confusing!!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX I have /inch HDMI LCD 800x480 if I am correct, website I posted (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD) is for exect same screen, and they have code to run it in terminal and install driver, I did that and got my OS file corrupted, i guess

Comment: see, there's a `LCD7-800x480-show`

Comment: @JaromandaX uh , I see so, u think it should be like this: 
git clone https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show.git 
cd LCD-show/
chmod +x LCD7-800x480-show
./LCD7-800x480-show

Comment: yeah, I guess if you have a 800x480 display, you'd want to configure for 800x480 - seems obvious